# What is the prefered way to expose a module version number?

Tags: python

What is the/is there a *prefered* way to expose a module version number?

- Python itself use the builtins tuple `sys.version_info`:

  ```
  >>> sys.version_info
  sys.version_info(major=3, minor=3, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
  ```
- MySQLdb (for example) use an *ordinary* tuple:

  ```
  >>> MySQLdb.version_info
  (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
  ```
- Some third party library use the string `__version__`

  ```
  >>> requests.__version__
  '1.2.3'
  ```
- Some frameworks use the tuple `VERSION`:

  ```
  >>> django.VERSION
  (1, 6, 0, 'alpha', 0)
  ```

... apparently, there are a lot of different usages in that matter!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [PEP 396](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/#specification), it should be `module.__version__`. According to that PEP, you should use the [Normalized Version](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/#the-new-versioning-algorithm) style in [PEP 386](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/) to decide how it should be written.

It looks like there is a draft version of [PEP 440](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) that will supplant 386.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the pointers to the corresponding PEP.